# Typescript makecode minecraft library

Tags: javascript, typescript, minecraft

I am new to minecraft and learning to use it. I have some questions regarding the javascript objects. The minecraft I am using is Windows 10 version. I can use the code connect to write javascript. However, how can I find out more about the javascript script functions? 
For example : I want to set the game start at day time, I would need to use 
gameplay.timeSet(DayTime.Day)

Where can I find the information like that to code minecraft??

Thanks a lot
Chun

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but that is not possible simply.
You can inject a 3rd party API if you would like, but this is know to destroy devices.